# Сортировка по состовному ключу

Tags: php

Появилась задача - отсортировать массив по составному ключу. Причём в разной направленности. Допустим, есть массив:

```
$arr = [
   ['amount' => 4, 'slots' => 10, 'str_sort' => '122_21'],
    ['amount' => 2, 'slots' => 8, 'str_sort' => '122_21'],
['amount' => 44, 'slots' => 10, 'str_sort' => '112_21'],
...
]
```

Я хотел создать функцию `sort`, которая бы принимала ключи для сортировки в порядке приортета и направление:

```
function arrSort(&$arr, $rules) 
{
   foreach ($arr as &$el)
        {
            $el['for_sort'] = [];

            foreach ($rules as $rule => $direction)
            {
                if($direction == 'desc')
                $el['for_sort'][] = -$el[$rule];
                else
                 $el['for_sort'][] = $el[$rule];

            $el['for_sort'] = implode('_', $el['for_sort']);
        }
  usort($arr, function($a, $b){
            return strcmp(
                    strtolower($a['for_sort']),
                    strtolower($b['for_sort'])
                );
        });
}

arrSort($arr, ['amount' => 'desc', 'slots' => 'asc', 'str_sort' => 'asc']);
```

Но, к сожалению, данная идея провалилась. Потому что, направленность сортировки я меняю с помощью знака минус, а это, во-первых не эффективно для строк (но я это специально допустил, потому что строки я знал что сортироваться будут по обычному), а вот например `amount` нужно делать чем больше, тем выше. Но и тут `strcmp` мне не помогла, потому что минусы она не считает частью чисел, считает это просто дефисом.

Как сделать универсальное решение для любого количества параметров?

**UPDATE:**
Решил благодаря предложенной @splash58 функции:

```
<?php 

    $arr = [
   ['amount' => 4, 'slots' => 10, 'str_sort' => '122_21'],
    ['amount' => 2, 'slots' => 8, 'str_sort' => '122_21'],
['amount' => 44, 'slots' => 10, 'str_sort' => '112_21']
];

function arrSort2(&$arr, $rules)  {
    $arrToSort = [];
    foreach ($rules as $rule => $direction)
    {
       $arrToSort[] = array_column($arr, $rule);
        $arrToSort[] = $direction;
    }

    $arrToSort[] = &$arr;

    call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $arrToSort);
}

arrSort2($arr, ['amount' => SORT_DESC, 'slots' => SORT_ASC, 'str_sort' => SORT_ASC]);
```

Comment: есть такая функция - array_multisort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть такая функция - [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

для первых двух условий выглядеть будет так

```
array_multisort(array_column($arr, 'amount'), SORT_DESC, array_column($arr, 'slots'), SORT_ASC, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

можете написать свой интерфейс, если хотите

Comment: Большое спасибо! Эта функция помогла!

Comment: да, не за что :)